# Trying to implement a promotion code box in php for an online store

Tags: php, promotion-code

I'm trying to make a promo code box in php such that I can give people different codes for specific discounts on items in my online store. The basic idea is to have them input the code into the box at time of purchase for a coupon-like effect.

I've been searching around and haven't been able to find anything regarding this or something of a similar nature.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's a basic stuff with a formula on you billing page which connect to the database and reach the coupon id. Be more precise.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some thoughts/ideas of my own that I used to create a coupon-like system. This should help to get you started in designing a backend.

1. You want the (let's call it
   'Coupon') to have the ability to be
   tied to specific items or not, as
   well as have the ability to be tied
   to Categories of items (multiple
   items).
2. The Coupon should be able to define
   either a set amount off or a set
   percentage off either a portion of
   the sub-total or the entire
   sub-total.
3. Tax should be calculated based off
   of pre-discount sub-total. You can
   choose to do it the other way, but
   this is a decision point to consider.
4. You should be able to specify a start date and end date for the coupon.
5. You should have the ability to track coupon usage by item and by user.  If you have abstract groups of users, then you should be able to track by user group as well.
6. You should be able to require other items in the coupon which are not discounted in order to get a discount on other items. (Buy `This` Get `That` Half Off types of deals)
7. You should be able to define a minimum number of Items until a coupon can take effect (Buy 3 Tires Get the 4th Free!), as well as a maximum number of times this can be applied (You may not want: Buy 30 Tires Get 10 Tires Free!)
8. You *can* decide to restrict certain coupons to a certain user or group of users.  You would need to find a way to enforce this restriction if you do.

Just reading this leads me to see at least 3 tables:

`Coupons`, `Item_Coupons`, `User_Coupons`

Where `Item_Coupons` and `User_Coupons` map your tables for Items and Users to Coupons.  You can also include other tables that may make things easier, such as `Coupons_RequiredItems` which is another map from Coupons to items that defines the required items for the coupon.  The structure of these tables depends heavily on precisely how you intend to implement this.

Of course, if your only intention is to provide X% off an individual Item, then following this would be way too complicated, but much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

The bad way:

```
switch($_GET['code']) {
  case "foo":
    $price -= $price * 0.1;
    break;
  case "bar":
    $price -= $price * 0.25;
    break;
  case "baz":
    $price -= $price * .33;
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Better would be to have the mapping code -> discount stored somewhere in a database and read it from there.